# syntax error with awk print

Tags: regex, shell, awk, nawk

for a text like the following:

```
std_out_file: ${ALGO_TOP}/dynamic/batchlog/JS030003-ara.stop.badb.out
```

I want the output to be:

```
$BATCHLOG_DIR/JS030003-ara.stop.badb.out
```

here is the code:

```
nawk '/std_out_file:|std_err_file:/ { split($2, a, /); if ( a[3]=="batchlog" ) print "$$BATCHLOG_DIR/"$3; else print "$$CONSOLELOG_DIR/"$3; }'
```

I got the following error:

```
nawk: illegal primary in regular expression ); if ( a[3]=="batchlog" ) print "$$BATCHLOG_DIR at ; if ( a[3]=="batchlog" ) print "$$BATCHLOG_DIR
 source line number 4
 context is
        /std_out_file:|std_err_file:/ { split($2, a, /); if ( a[3]=="batchlog" ) print "$$BATCHLOG_DIR/", $3; else print >>>  " <<<
```

where did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third argument of `split` function is a regex. You should place your `/` inside `split` function like:

```
split($2, a, /\//)
```

Notice that `/` needs to be escaped to let `awk` know that is it not start or end of the `regex` pattern.

Having said that, you can avoid the `split` altogether by setting the delimiter to `/`. Something like:

```
awk -F'/' '/std_out_file:|std_err_file:/{print ($(NF-1)=="batchlog" ? "$BATCH" : "$CONSOLE") "LOG_DIR/"$NF}' file
```

Where you test the second last field `$(NF-1)` to be `batchlog`. The ternary op is basically doing the same thing as your `if-else` condition.

Comment: +1; also note that `"$$BATCHLOG_DIR/"` and `"$$CONSOLELOG_DIR/"` will literally just print that - unclear whether the OP wanted to reference shell variables. Judging by the sample output, the first `$` could simply be dropped.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks, you are right. I just copy-pasted from OP's input. Updated now.

Comment: +1 You could also move the common part out of the ternary expression: `print ($(NF-1)=="batchlog" ? "$BATCH" : "$CONSOLE") "LOG_DIR/"$NF`

Comment: That is indeed the right way. Thanks @EdMorton for always adding value to my answers. Have updated the solution to reflect your suggestion.